# How to identify the name of sqlite database table which ttk.Treeview loads data from?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, for-loop, treeview, ttk

I have a `tkinter` application written in python3. It has one main `tk.Frame`. Using `for` loop I build there two `ttk.LabelFrame`s, then each frame gets its `ttk.Treeview`. Each of those treeviews loads its data from different table (named *aliens1* and *aliens2*):

```
class Application:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        
        self.database = Database(self.master, self)
        self.turns_frame = TurnsFrame(self.master, self)

class TurnsFrame:
    def __init__(self, master, app):
        self.master = master
        self.app = app
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master, bd=2)
        
        # Create LabelFrames and their Treeviews
        for i in range(3):
            ap_frame = tk.LabelFrame(self.frame, text="Alien Player {}".format(str(i+1)))
            ap_frame.grid(row=0, column=i)

            tv = tk.ttk.Treeview(ap_frame,
                                 columns=tuple(range(1, 12)),
                                 show="headings",
                                 height=30)
            tv.pack()

            ... creating columns ...

            # Create rows
            with self.app.database.db:
                self.app.database.cursor.execute("SELECT turn, econ_rolls, econ_rolls_extra, cp_fleet, "
                                             "cp_tech, cp_def, fleet_launch, roll_econ, roll_fleet, "
                                             "roll_tech, roll_def FROM aliens{}".format(str(i+1)))
                rows = self.app.database.cursor.fetchall()

                for r in rows:
                    tv.insert("", "end", values=r)

            # Bind row double-click
            tv.bind("<Double-1>", self.get_turn_number)

    def get_turn_number(self, event):
        item_id = event.widget.focus()
        item = event.widget.item(item_id)
        values = item["values"]
        turn_id = values[0]

        print("Turn: ", turn_id)
        return turn_id

class Database:
    def __init__(self, master, app):
        self.master = master
        self.app = app
        self.folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

        self.db = self.create_connection(self.folder)
        self.cursor = self.db.cursor()

    def create_connection(self, f):
        db = None
        try:
            db = sqlite3.connect(os.path.join(f, "aliens.db"))
        except sqlite3.Error as e:
            print(e)

        return db

    def initialize_tables(self, nr):
    # SOME OTHER FRAME CALLS THIS FUNCTION AND GIVES THE VARIABLE 'nr'
        with self.db:
            for i in range(1, nr+1):
                # print("Creating table aliens{}".format(str(i)))
                self.cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE aliens{}(".format(i) +
                                    "turn INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                                    "econ_rolls INTEGER,"
                                    "econ_rolls_extra INTEGER,"
                                    "cp_fleet INTEGER,"
                                    "cp_tech INTEGER,"
                                    "cp_def INTEGER,"
                                    "fleet_launch STRING,"
                                    "roll_econ STRING,"
                                    "roll_fleet STRING,"
                                    "roll_tech STRING,"
                                    "roll_def STRING)")

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    main_app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It looks fine and is working fine, looks like this
[application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xodm4.png).

Now I can double-click on any row and it executes `self.get_turn_number`.
Great.
For further work I need to get the database table name which it loads its rows from (depending on which treeview I double-clicked - first one *Alien player 1* or the second one *Alien player 2*). Alien player 1 loads its data from table *alien1* and player 2 from *aliens2*.

I searched the documentation but found nothing regarding this stuck in `ttk.Treeview`. It also seems that no one had had this problem before. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Could you show us how you instantiate your class too

Comment: Code added. The main app is a class and the turns_frame is instantiated in its __init__. (I´m quite new to Python so the structure may not be the most pythonic:/)

Comment: Which other frame? Both LabelFrames (Alien Player1 and Alien Player 2) are created in the "for" loop - __init__ of class TurnsFrame. Did you mean that?

Comment: I am sorry, I mean the other `class`. I wanted to see how you pass the database and so on.

Comment: One thing you can do is. Store the database name in variables? and pass that variable as the `app` parameter in `__init__` or make a new parameter name, `db_name` and pass the path on.

Comment: I think you have it right there, try `print(self.folder)` and check if it what you want.

Comment: I added the class Database. I am not sure I understand but I need to detect the corresponding table name from the database, not the database´s name itself... I mean there is one database common for both aliens and it has two separate tables - one for aliens1 and the second for aliens2

Comment: When I print(self.app.database.folder), it shows the folder where the whole db is, that´s right but not what I need to accomplish.. By double-click on row in Alien Player 2 treeview I need to get the name 'alien2' because this table is the source for rows in player2.

Comment: is it possible for you to give a code that generates some rows in the tables?

Comment: Then that `alien1` and `alien2` might be table names, and not database names, if im not wrong the database file name is `your_foldname.db`, I thought you wanted to access that

Comment: I added two lines with filling rows to the treeview. The project is not secret, I am just trying to show the important parts...

Comment: Cool Cloud - `self.folder` is e.g. C:\test. The database is C:\test\aliens.db but I need to get to its table names c:\test\aliens.db\aliens1 (or aliens2)

Comment: Does the binding even work? Have you tried something demo? Like `print('Hello')` inside the func and does the binding work?

Comment: Yes, it works. I tried printing the turn number and it was ok.

Comment: Binding works with all the treeviews or just one?

Comment: My problem would solve if there was the way how to pass an argument to the function called by binding. Now there is `tv.bind("<Double-1>", self.calculate_econ_phase)`. If I could be able to have `tv.bind("<Double-1>", self.calculate_econ_phase(tablename)` it would solve it but If I add the (tablename), it throws the error. It must be called without arguments

Comment: Well, it works... on both? Actually I don´t know because both tables hve the same data. Testing was: when I dbl-clicked on row 5 in Alien1 treeview, it printed 5. When I dbl-clicked on row e.g. 13 in Alien2 treeview, it printed 13. I hope it get its values from their corresponding table (alien1 or alien2)

Comment: I edited the code - now the double click calls `self.get_row_number`. I tested this and it seemed to work

Comment: Did you try out my answer?

Comment: If you think your answer to put the table names into variables - I could do that. But I need this variable in `self.get_row_number` and I can´t see the way how to pass it there - binding dblclick to the function `self.get_row_number` with an argument throws an error. It the function itself accepts only `event` (`def get_row_number(self, event)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I just noticed the `for` loop you are on. What you could do is pass the number on to the function and then run it out, like:

```
.... # Same code
    tv.bind("<Double-1>", lambda e,num=i: self.calculate_econ_phase(num)

def calculate_econ_phase(self,num):
    print(f'Alien{num}')
```

Posting as answer because too long for comments.

Comment: Great! With `e, num=i+1` it really prints the player number. So now, How to integrate `event` to be able to get the turn number? This lambda is still quite beyond my knowledge...

Comment: What do you mean? Why do you need event here? You just have to double click on a widget right?

Comment: Look at the `def get_turn_number(self, event)` - I need the `event` to get the dblclicked row value (e.g. turn number as it is in the question code)

Comment: I´ve got it! `tv.bind("<Double-1>", lambda e,num=i+1: self.get_turn_number(e, num)` and `def get_turn_number(self, event, num): ...` works! It prints the right player number and right turn number. Thank you for your advice and time!

Comment: Although not the precise answer to the question I´m marking the answer as accepted as it helped me to solve the problem.

Comment: Just take a look at your function definition and bind, its all the same, except you changed the name.

Comment: Yes I changed the function name only to show how I got to the turn number. Now I understand how it works and what and where should I put these variables. Thanks!